# col-md, col-xs for Height in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I was wondering if there's a way I could simulate the col-md, col-xs for the height attribute of one of my CSS class. I understand I have to use LESS in my CSS, but I can't manage to get it to work.

In this example, I want a height of 10px if the screen is a mobile phone (768px). Do I have to compile the LESS somehow ?

```
.master-body {
    border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
    background-image: url(../../ressources/noise_lines.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 75vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .master-body {
        height: 10px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `min-width` to `max-width` to target all small devices.